# Overriding a component method

Tags: vuejs2, google-visualization

I'm using [VueCharts](https://github.com/haydenbbickerton/vue-charts) which is a Google Charts plugin for vue.

I'm trying to give the newer Material Design looks to the charts. I've tried passing "google.charts.Bar" to chart-type prop and it did work. However, many of the options are ignored because, as stated in the [Google Charts docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#creating-material-bar-charts), the options object needs to be converted by using `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options)`, something the plugin doesn't do.

Looking at the source, the plugin installs a 'vue-chart' component. This component uses `ChartWrapper` to handle loading the chart libraries, like so:

```
methods: {
    buildWrapper (chartType, dataTable, options, containerId) {
      let wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: chartType,
        dataTable: dataTable,
        options: options,
        containerId: containerId
      })

      return wrapper
    },
```

So all I need is to override this method to convert the options before passing them to the ChartWrapper.

But how? I haven't found a way to simply override a component method in vue docs. I could create a new component and pass the converted options down, but I need access to the google object, which is only loaded internally by the plugin.

I have also read I could use mixins, but it's not clear how. This doesn't work:

```
Vue.component('MyCustomChart', {
    mixins: ['vue-chart'],
    methods: {
        buildWrapper (chartType, dataTable, options, containerId) {
            let wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                chartType: chartType,
                dataTable: dataTable,
                options: google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options), // that's all I need
                containerId: containerId
            })

            return wrapper
        },
    }
})
```

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. 
>   (found in MyCustomChart)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Vue's extend method to customize plugin components.

In your case:

```
import VueCharts from 'vue-charts'  
Vue.use(VueCharts);

const Base = Vue.options.components["vue-chart"];
const CustomChart = Base.extend({
  methods: {
    buildWrapper (chartType, dataTable, options, containerId) {
      let wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: chartType,
        dataTable: dataTable,
        options: google.charts.Bar.coverOptions(options),
        containerId: containerId
      })

      return wrapper
    },
  })
}

Vue.component('MyCustomChart', CustomChart);
```

(credit to Bert Evans for noting that you need to reference the base component from `Vue.options.components` before extending to customize)

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. `vue-charts` is a plugin. `vue-chart` is a globally added component.

Comment: It worked for me. If `vue-chart` component provides a property to specify the options, then overriding the method isn't the way to go. But, addressing the question, this is how I would override methods from a component plugin.

Comment: Is there a reason you would choose lodash over Vue.extend?

Comment: how would you do that with a component plugin?

Comment: In this case, extend twice; `const Base = Vue.extend(VueChart)`, then `const CustomChart = Base.extend({...})`. Anyway, I was just curious. thanks :)

Comment: I ended up forking the repo and placing checks in `buildWrapper` to conditionally use `convertOptions` based on `chartType`. But thanks for showing how to customize the component. I'll try that later and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: I believe I led you astray. See my updated answer. Ideally you can edit and @RegularEverydayNormalGuy will accept yours.

Comment: I had actually been testing with the wrong npm module `'vue-chart'`, which is just a component and not a plugin, which was why your initial comment worked for me. But I updated my answer so that it should work for the asker. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

I played around with this a bit and I misled @thanksd above with my recommendation on what to extend. One way that works is this:

```
import VueChart from "vue-charts";

Vue.use(VueChart);

const BaseChart = Vue.options.components["vue-chart"];
const CustomChart = BaseChart.extend({
  methods:{
    buildWrapper (chartType, dataTable, options, containerId) {
      let wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: chartType,
        dataTable: dataTable,
        options: google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options),
        containerId: containerId
      })

      return wrapper
    }
  }
});

Vue.component("custom-chart", CustomChart);
```

**Further Explanation**

As I thought, extending VueChart either through Vue's native extend, or through `lodash`, will not achieve the expected results. The result of importing VueChart is a [plugin definition](https://github.com/haydenbbickerton/vue-charts/blob/master/src/main.js). Both `lodash` and `Vue` will happily accept that as an object to extend, but neither will result in a Vue component. Trying to use the result of either will result in the error mentioned in the question, "template or render function not defined". That error is absolutely true; extending `VueChart` extends an install function with a single method.

So how do you get the object to extend? `vue-charts` doesn't expose it. The install just calls `Vue.component('vue-chart', Chart)`.

Fortunately, Vue makes the globally installed components through `Vue.options.components`. By extending `Vue.options.components["vue-chart"]` we get a proper Vue component definition.

Finally, I was surprised `google` was not available to @RegularEverydayNormalGuy. It has to be available; `vue-chart` uses it. But he's right, it's not available *immediately*. `vue-chart` loads the script asynchronously. Again, the plugin unfortunately doesn't make it available to you in any way, [it just initializes itself after it's asynchronously loaded](https://github.com/haydenbbickerton/vue-charts/blob/master/src/components/chart.js#L112). There are ways to work around that, but at that point you should just probably submit a pull request.

## Original Answer

`options` is a property on `vue-chart`. Why not just pass in the converted options?

```
new Vue({
    data:{
        convertedOptions: google.charts.Bar.convertOptions({<my options>})
    }
})
```

And in the template

```
<vue-chart :options="convertedOptions"></vue-chart>
```

Comment: @RegularEverydayNormalGuy You're right. It's not *immediately* available.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Wish I could accept both.